# Как вернуть значение из Function Expression?

Tags: javascript

Имеется такая функция, которая считывает данные из файла:

```
function read_file(local_path){
    let dataFile;
    fs.readFile(local_path + "my_file.csv", "utf8",
        function (error, data){
        if (error) throw error;
        return  data;
        });
}

async function run() {
    await console.dir(read_file(local_path));
}

run();
```

Как вернуть значение из функции внутри **readFile()** и возможно ли это?

Comment: Используйте `readFileSync()` или используйте `await readFile()` без коллбека

Comment: Да, уже использовал readFileSync(), спасибо

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
const readFile = (path) => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        fs.readFile(path, "utf8", (err, fileData) => {
            if(err) return reject(err);
            resolve(fileData);
        })
    })
}

const run = async() => {
    const fileData = await readFile("./folder/file.extension");

    console.log(fileData)
}
```